# warning: data definition has no type or storage class = flite compilation warning

Tags: c, flite

vi example.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "flite.h"
register_cmu_us_kal();
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
 cst_voice *v;
 if(argc!=2)
 {
  fprintf(stderr,"usage:file_test FILE\n");
  exit(-1);
 }
 flite_init();
 v=register_cmu_us_kal(NULL);
 flite_file_to_speech(argv[1],v,"play");
 return 0;
}
```

Compile:
desktop:

```
~/flite-1.4-release$ gcc example.c -I./include/ -L./build/i386-linux-gnu/lib -lflite -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_cmulex -lflite_usenglish -lflite_cmu_us_rms -lflite_cmu_time_awb -lflite_cmu_us_slt -lflite_cmu_us_awb -lm -o example


example.c:3: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
example.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
example.c:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

I have explored the contents of the lib folder below.

desktop:

```
~/flite-1.4-release$ ls
ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS  config.guess   configure     example          flite.sln   lang      mkinstalldirs  src        wince
bin               config.log     configure.in  example.c        -I          main      palm           testsuite  windows
build             config.status  COPYING       Exports.def      include     Makefile  README         test.txt
config            config.sub     doc           fliteDll.vcproj  install-sh  missing   sapi           tools
```

desktop:

```
~/flite-1.4-release/build/i386-linux-gnu/lib$ ls
libflite.a                      libflite_cmu_us_awb.shared.a    libflite_cmu_us_kal.so.1      libflite.shared.a
libflite_cmulex.a               libflite_cmu_us_awb.so          libflite_cmu_us_kal.so.1.4    libflite.so
libflite_cmulex.shared.a        libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.1        libflite_cmu_us_rms.a         libflite.so.1
libflite_cmulex.so              libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.1.4      libflite_cmu_us_rms.shared.a  libflite.so.1.4
libflite_cmulex.so.1            libflite_cmu_us_kal16.a         libflite_cmu_us_rms.so        libflite_usenglish.a
libflite_cmulex.so.1.4          libflite_cmu_us_kal16.shared.a  libflite_cmu_us_rms.so.1      libflite_usenglish.shared.a
libflite_cmu_time_awb.a         libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so        libflite_cmu_us_rms.so.1.4    libflite_usenglish.so
libflite_cmu_time_awb.shared.a  libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so.1      libflite_cmu_us_slt.a         libflite_usenglish.so.1
libflite_cmu_time_awb.so        libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so.1.4    libflite_cmu_us_slt.shared.a  libflite_usenglish.so.1.4
libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1      libflite_cmu_us_kal.a           libflite_cmu_us_slt.so
libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1.4    libflite_cmu_us_kal.shared.a    libflite_cmu_us_slt.so.1
libflite_cmu_us_awb.a           libflite_cmu_us_kal.so          libflite_cmu_us_slt.so.1.4
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by changing your method declaration:

```
register_cmu_us_kal();
```

To

```
cst_voice *register_cmu_us_kal();
```

This tells the compiler that the method 
`register_cmu_us_kal();` returns a `cst_voice *` instead of an `int` which is the default, which, when you assign this:

```
v = register_cmu_us_kal(NULL);
```

First, you are calling the function with parameters where you define it without parameters, secondly it is warning you that you are trying to assign a `int` to a `cst_voice *`.

Comment: Happy to help. Just remember to up vote and accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3):

The following declares a function that takes unspecified arguments and returns an `int`:

```
register_cmu_us_kal();
```

When you call it, you assign its result to a variable of type `cst_voice*`:

```
v=register_cmu_us_kal(NULL);
```

The compiler warns you about this conversion.

I think the best course of action is to provide a proper prototype for `register_cmu_us_kal` (perhaps by including the relevant header file).